How to view Docker Compose logs by profile with dependencies?
I have many similar services in my docker-compose.yml that can be split in two groups where each application depends on the corresponding proxy. In order to manage them more easily I added profiles like so:
services:
  # proxies
  proxy-one:
    image: example/proxy
    profiles: [proxy-one, proxy, one, all]
  ...

  # applications
  application-one:
    image: example/application
    profiles: [application-one, application, one, all]
    depends_on:
      - proxy-one
  ...

Now I can manage them using these profiles without need to specify each particular service, like:
docker compose --profile proxy up -d or
docker compose --profile one restart or
docker compose --profile all down
But I can't view logs for applications only in the same way using profiles because they have dependencies:
$ docker compose --profile application logs
service "application-one" depends on undefined service "proxy-one": invalid compose project

Is there any way to leverage profiles for viewing logs as well?
Or I still need to list each service individually because of the dependencies?
I understand why this dependency is important for other commands like start/stop etc., but for logs it defeats the purpose.

The documentation says that depends_on should share a common profile. Does the behavior change is you use --profile=one or --profile=all which are explicitly shared profiles?

It works with a shared profile but then I see both logs from proxy and application containers. As I have many of those it's not convenient to read, that's why I'm looking for  a better way to view application logs only without mentioning every service.
